# CUDA Direct3D interoperability deprecated?

Tags: cuda, direct3d

I have been looking through CUDA documentation, and [Direct 3D 11 interoperability](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__D3D11__DEPRECATED.html#group__CUDA__D3D11__DEPRECATED) and it is saying that it is deprecated. The documentation, however, does not say what is the new way to do it, or why is it deprecated. I was unable to find answers on Google. Does anyone know?

Comment: Looks like individual resource mapping of [OpenGL](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__GL.html#group__CUDA__GL) and [Direct3D](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__D3D11.html#group__CUDA__D3D11) have been deprecated in favor of generic [Graphic interop](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__GRAPHICS.html#group__CUDA__GRAPHICS) since CUDA 5.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CUDA Direct3D interop is not deprecated.  Some methods are deprecated.

The D3D11 non-deprecated API [is here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__D3D11.html#group__CUDART__D3D11).  The deprecated API [is here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__D3D11__DEPRECATED.html#group__CUDART__D3D11__DEPRECATED).

The [CUDA samples](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#simple-d3d11-texture) demonstrate non-deprecated methods of D3D interop.

Also, CUDA 6.5 [specifically deprecates](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html#deprecated-features) D3D9 activity with `IDirect3D9` objects, which should be replaced with `IDirect3D9ex` objects instead.

Answer (score 2):

CUDA-Direct3D is actually very active and updated.

In CUDA 10 they added New interoperability between CUDA and graphics APIs, including **Vulkan** and **DX12**.

[1] https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit/whatsnew

[2] https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#graphics